# How to update multiple data (status) in firebase database, Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a simple ecommerce app, and i want to update the order status for more than one product, i can update status for a single product but not multiple products. i am self-taught programmer/learner

My database:

```
Products:

01525415522022
pOrderId: 
"01525415522022"
pid: 
"PID13442022"
productPrice: 
"8765"
status: 
"not paid"

01525915522022
pOrderId: 
"01525915522022"
pid: 
"PID12223605222022"
productPrice: 
"53686"
status: 
"not paid"
```

And here is my code for single item status update

```
DatabaseReference updateRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("AdminCart")
       .child(firebaseUser.getPhoneNumber()).child("Products");
HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
hashMap.put("status", "paid");
deleteRef.updateChildren(hashMap)
```

Comment: Instead of describing what your database looks like, please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Please also indicate the exact data you want to update.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
updateRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
             for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) { 
              String key=datas.getKey();
              ref.child(key).child("status").setValue("paid");
                }
             } 
          }
            @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

           }
     });
```